# TFS 2017 Update 3 to Azure Dev Ops

Tags: azure, tfs, migration

I have a situation where I need to upgrade from TFS 2017 Update 3 to a version of Azure Dev Ops.  The immediate challenge that I am facing is that I cannot find the old TFSMigrator.exe package that is supposed to assist in the migration and validation.
Admittingly, I am probably putting the cart before the horse with this, however wanted to try to validate the datasets would migrate before getting too deep.  (This is because I have been part of way too many manual migrations because the upgrade paths did not exist or the configurations were nonstandard.)

The Migrator.exe that is available now (and seems to have wiped the TFSMigrator off the web) tells me that The version of this tool is not intended to be used with this version of Azure DevOps Server. I get it, I am pointing it to TFS, but how would one go about this?

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure to check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-overview?view=azure-devops

Comment: The data migration tool for Azure DevOps supports the two latest releases of Azure DevOps Server at a given time. Releases include updates and major releases. Currently the following versions of Azure DevOps Server are supported for import:

Azure DevOps Server 2019.1.1
Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behavior, since your TFS/Azure DevOps Version is not qualified.

> The data migration tool for Azure DevOps supports the two latest
>   releases of Azure DevOps Server at a given time. Releases include
>   updates and major releases. Currently the following versions of Azure
>   DevOps Server are supported for import:
>
> - Azure DevOps Server 2019.1.1
> - Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1
>
> [*Source Link*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-overview?view=azure-devops#supported-azure-devops-server-versions-for-import)

Please first upgrade your TFS2017 to Azure DevOps Server2019 update 1 first. Then follow this [migration guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/migrate/) to import data to Azure DevOps Service if you need.

About how to update TFS2017 to Azure DevOps Server 2019, please take a look at these useful links:

- [How to migrate collections from TFS 2017 to Azure DevOps Server 2019 (Different DB servers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320698/how-to-migrate-collections-from-tfs-2017-to-azure-devops-server-2019-different)
- [Update OnPrem TFS  to AzureDevOps Server 2019](https://blog.codeinside.eu/2019/04/30/update-onprem-tfs-2018-to-azuredevops-server-2019/)

Answer (score 2):

You have to upgrade from TFS 2017 to a supported version of Azure DevOps Server. The on-prem version that can be migrated to Azure DevOps is a sliding window that changes as Microsoft releases new versions. 2017 is no longer a supported version for this kind of migration.