# Azure DevOps Server migration & upgrade

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020

I am preparing for a process of migrating and upgrading our on-premise Azure DevOps Server instance. I tried to collect information on the best practices to perform these tasks, but I am still not sure, what is the best way to get this done.
What I want to do:

**Current state**

Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1.1 on Windows Server 2016 with databases on Windows Server 2016 + MS SQL Server 2016

And I would like to move to:

**Final State**

Azure DevOps Server 2020 on Windows Server 2019 with databases on Windows Server 2019 + MS SQL Server 2019

I read topics on migrating Azure DevOps instances app tier and data tier using back/restore procedures, but there has to be used exactly the same version od SQL Server. [Restore data to a different server than the current one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance?view=azure-devops-2020)

What is a preferred series of steps to do this?
First upgrade Azure DevOps Server from 2019 to 2020 with the current OS and SQL setup, then move databases to newer SQL instance on new VM (I didn't find any documentation on how to do that) and then move app tier to new VM and point to new DBs?

Additionally, to make things even more complicated, the set of VMs will be in another domain, I don't know whether it is an issue, but the current setup uses domain service users as domain\TFSService, TFSBuild etc. to run the Azure DevOps Server instance, Db, build agents and so on.

Any help to start me off is appreciated.
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Hi @KevinLu-MSFT I have commented your answer some time ago and I would like to determine if the procedure specified is the correct one. Can you please hep me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. The migration of SQL Database requires the same version of SQL.

So I suggest that you can migrate databases first, then upgrade the SQL server version, finally install or upgrade azure devops server 2020.

Here [a ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56375596/13464420) about recommended steps. Since [SQL server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops-2020#azure-sql-database-and-sql-server) also supports azure devops server 2020, you can refer to the following steps:

- Install the SQL Server matching your original environment.
- Attach the databases
- Install a version of Azure Devops Server(Azure Devops Server 2020) that supports your SQL server version.
- Refer to [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/move-or-clone-tfs-from-one-hardware-to-another-in-tfs-2017-2018/) to configure the Azure Devops Server with the backup database
- Detach databases and uninstall SQL Server
- Install the desired SQL Server version  with the same instance name.
- Attach databases
- Use the [TfsConfig command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd?view=azure-devops-2020#remapdbs) to configure the new SQL Server for Azure Devops Server.

> the set of VMs will be in another domain, I don't know whether it is an issue.

This is environment migration. You could first complete the hardware move, and then change the environment.

Here is [a doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-across-domains?view=azure-devops-2020) about detailed steps.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I would like to ask some specifics about the process but I don't have enough characters in the comment. Is there a way to communicate directly?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid there is no more direct way. If you have any questions, please feel free to let me know via comment ,or you can update your question to show detailed information, I will try my best to help you.

Comment: OK. I did the upgrade to ADOS 2020 because I had to due to a deadline before the original answer. So that is out of the way. Now I tried to merge somehow the instructions int the answer and in the documentation for my scenario and I came up with this:
1. Do a back up of ADOS Dbs using the Mng Console BackUp Feature
2. Install SQL Server matching the version of the old one. But can I install it on the new WS 2019? That’s OK?
3. Install ADOS 2020 on new SQL Server but do not configure it and restore the DBs which I backed up in step 1.

Comment: 4. Detach databases and uninstall SQL Server.
5. Uninstall the ADOS
6. Install new version of SQL Server with the same instance name.
7. Attach databases to SQL instance
8. Install ADOS on the new app tier server with WS 2019
9. Attach the ADOS Dbs to the new app tier.
Does this look right to you?
In addition. When should I uninstall the original ADOS app tier?

Comment: Hi. Can I expect any more help on this @kevin-lu-msft?